# glDrawArrays takes long on first call using OpenGL ES on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to use multiple GLSL fragment shaders with OpenGL ES on iOS 7 and upwards. The shaders itself are running fine after the first call to glDrawArrays. Nevertheless, the very first call to glDrawArrays after the shaders and their program have been compiled and linked takes ages to complete. Afterwards some pipeline or whatever seems to have been loaded and everything goes smooth. Any ideas what the cause of this issue are and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually helped speeding up the first draw call was the following (which is fine in my use case since I'm rendering a video so no depth testing is needed).

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTHTEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that your shaders may not be fully compiled until you use them the first time. They might have been translated to some kind of intermediate form when you call `glCompileShader()`, which would be enough for the driver to provide a compile status and to act as if the shaders had been compiled. But the full compilation and optimization could well be deferred until the first draw call that uses the shader program.

A commonly used technique for games is to render a few frames without actually displaying them while some kind of intro screen is still shown to the user. This prevents the user from seeing stuttering that could otherwise result from all kinds of possible deferred initialization or data loading during the first few frames.

You could also look into using binary shaders to reduce slowdowns from shader compilation. See `glShaderBinary()` in the ES 2.0 documentation.

Comment: sounds like a good idea. unfortunately, iOS does not support shader binaries :(